# Page.AsyncTimeout - endless timeout?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, c#-5.0, asp.net-4.5

I saw [*an example*](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg30/index.html) of `forever iframe` implementation ( comet simulation )  , so I decided to test it but with  the addition of **asynchronous** approach  , so that there will be no blocking.

Pretty simple :

I have a page (`index.html`) with hidden `iframe` *which has SRC of*  `AdminPush.aspx`:

```
/*1*/           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
/*2*/           {
/*3*/               UpdateMessage();
/*4*/           }
/*5*/   
/*6*/   
/*7*/           protected void UpdateMessage()
/*8*/           {
/*9*/               HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
/*10*/               Response.Write("<script  >parent.UpdateMessage(DateTime.Now.Second)</script>");
/*11*/               Response.Flush();
/*12*/   
/*13*/               //async part goes here  !!
/*14*/               this.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(async cancellationToken =>
/*15*/                                       {
/*16*/                                            await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken);
/*17*/                                            UpdateMessage();
/*18*/                                       }));
/*19*/           }
```

On the `AdminPush.aspx` Page I added :

`Async="true"`

On the html page (`index.html`) I added :

```
function UpdateMessage(Message)
        {
          console.log(Message);
        }


    function setupAjax() //body Onload - calls it.
    {
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.src = "adminpush.aspx"; 
        iframe.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
```

So basically the iframe is being injected with script comands  , which updates the parent of the iframe which is `index.html`.

It is working.

But when I tested it  - it stopped updating after 45 seconds.

I thought it had to do with requestTimeout prop in web.config - but it wasnt.

It was related to the missing `AsyncTimeOut` prop in the `AdminPush.aspx` page.

**Question #1:**

According to [**msdn**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.asynctimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) AsyncTimeout :

> Gets or sets a value indicating the time-out interval used when
>   processing asynchronous **tasks**.

But it also says :

> A TimeSpan that contains the allowed time interval for completion of
>   the asynchronous **task**. The default time interval is 45 seconds.

**please notice that I "delay" 2 sec every time**

at first I set the timeout to 1 minute , but then it failed also. I thought that the timeout should be  regarding **each** operation   , and not to `sum(all async operations)`

Why is it like that ? it suppose to be timeout for async task ! (single) but it behaves as `sum(tasks)`

The wording here are misleading. any clarification ?

**Question #2:**

I need to set it to *max* value. *what* is that value ? but still ,  I need it so support a browser for a very long time. so I'm afraid that this value won't help either.

Is there any way I can RESET this value (after n cycles) ?

*I know that there are other solutions/libraries like signalR which are doing the job, still, it does not prevent learning how other stuff are done.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of Asynchronous Pages is to free IIS so more users can be served, if you create a page that "never" finishes, you will eat up all your resources.

That been said... if you still want to do it...

We "know" (documentation), Asynchronous Pages work by splitting the execution of the page in 2... everything BEFORE the Background Tasks and everything AFTER the tasks, in that way IIS can process more requests while the background tasks finish their work. (there is more to it, but that is enough for now)

So... they ***"must"*** be creating some kind of **Task Manager** (like a root/main task) that executes all the registered tasks in sequence, in that way IIS starts processing the page, fires up the task manager, frees IIS, the task manager keeps processing the tasks and when it finishes, it returns control to IIS.

That would explain why the AsyncTimeout controls all the registered tasks instead of one-by-one (The timeout is actually applied to the Task Manager).

I tested a variation of your code  with a timeout of 6000 seconds and it works:

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ProcessTask));
}

protected async Task ProcessTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "<br/>");
    Response.Flush();
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ProcessTask));
}
```

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sample03.Default" Async="true" AsyncTimeout="6000" %>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any difference between your code vs my code ? **Also** —   As my question states , I need it to be infinitely  (for example like sR does). 6000 seconds is fine. but still has limits. is there any way of re-setting the timeout ?  ( so it will never end ? )

Comment: Difference: Not really... just prefer to avoid "async" in a lambda expression because it could not be executed in the way you expect (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx), I removed the Content-Type because: You do not need it, and even if you do, you are setting it in each call and http headers will only be sent to the client once. / 

Timeout: As far as I know, you cannot set an "infinite" timeout nor reset it. 

Workaround: Make the last call (before timing out) a "refresh" command, in your client refresh the iframe and that will cause the "timer" to start again

Comment: – Which will force me  to use index numbers cuz meanwhile  , while re-connection , a message could been sent....

Comment: A long pulling page will not guarantee that al. messages "reach" to the client... anyways... I tried to help, hope you find your answer.